# git push hangs indefinitely when using ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to push to a git repo. When I push, it hangs indefinitely.

I know that this is an SSH issue, because using `git remote set-url origin` to set the origin to the https repo address fixed the problem. But I would prefer to access my git repo through SSH.

Using these commands to stop/ restart the ssh agent works ***sometimes***, for a single git push:

```
launchctl stop /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent 

launchctl start /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent
```

But I'd prefer a better long-term approach.

Comment: Can you offer any more detail here? `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` before the push could help pinpoint where things are getting stuck, but without that information all I can do is offer condolences.

Comment: or, to identify whether it is an ssh issue or a git issue: run `ssh -v [gituser]@[host]` from the same terminal